# How to enable Android Virtual Devices (AVD)

Tags: linux, android-studio, react-native, android-virtual-device

I am starting to learn react-native but upon installation of Android-Studio I couldn't get the AVD button to be clickable (enable). As showned below the icon next (right) to the down-arrow icon is gey out. I needed to open the AVD in order to successfully run `react-native run-android`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screen there is error described: you don't have Build Tools. **Click on the blue link "Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project".**

Then go to **Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager** and click icon "**+Create Virtual Device**" (icon in lower left part of dialog window). On the next screens you will configure your VD (system, parameters) and you will have to **download system image**. It must be downloaded and selected to create Virtual Device. After that your VD should be accessible either by icon in main window or by list in Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager.